# what is web server side timeout?

Tags: http, webserver

I know the http client will have **connection timeout** if the connection not built at the define time. Also there has a **read timeout**,  it’s the time before the first byte response byte send from the server side.

Now my question is the server will send timeout response with response code 408. What this really mean? What situation will cause server send 408? What’s the underneath mechanism socket timeout on Linux? How the web server detect this time out?

Thanks Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`408`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.7) status code indicates that the server would like to shut down an unused connection with the client. It's defined in the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231):

> [**6.5.7.  408 Request Timeout**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.7)
>
> The `408` (Request Timeout) status code indicates that the server did
> not receive a complete request message within the time that it was
> prepared to wait.  A server SHOULD send the "close" connection option in the response, since `408` implies that
> the server has decided to close the connection rather than continue
> waiting.  If the client has an outstanding request in transit, the
> client MAY repeat that request on a new connection.